# Restore DBs from old version wamp to new version wamp

Tags: mysql, wamp

I had wamp2.4 installed. I uninstalled and then install wamp2.5. Now I have 2 folders in **"C:\wamp\bin\mysql"**

- mysql5.6.12
- mysql5.6.17

I copied all DB folders from **mysql5.6.12** to **mysql5.6.17**.

I go to phpmyadmin and all DBs are listed there and then I clicked on a table xyz and it says xyz doesn't exists.

Any Solution????

Answer (score 0):

Even better option is first you have to take logical backup of your db (can use mysqldump) and then restore after upgrading mysql version.

Now as you are saying that you have moved all files from old folder to new folder so assuming that all related (myisam as well innodb engine) files also have been moved. So you need to check permissions as mysql should have permission on this new mysql folder.

Comment: check what following command is showing : "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir'"

Comment: it directs to newer version of mysql folder
also default storage engine is innodb ....